# How to convert my linearLayout to GridView/GridLayout

Tags: android, gridview, android-linearlayout, android-gridlayout

How can I convert my linear layout as seen below to a grid view? So basically I need it to be 3 columns and 2 rows (in landscape orientation). No borders also.

The sample project is uploaded **[here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70475776/multiPlayer.zip)**.

[image]

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/video_1_surfaceview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/video_2_surfaceview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/video_3_surfaceview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/video_4_surfaceview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/video_5_surfaceview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/video_6_surfaceview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE:** And this is my onCreate() method and initialization in the class:

```
public class MultipleVideoPlayActivity extends Activity implements OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener, OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = "MediaPlayer";
    private static final int[] SURFACE_RES_IDS = { R.id.video_1_surfaceview, R.id.video_2_surfaceview };

    private MediaPlayer[] mMediaPlayers = new MediaPlayer[SURFACE_RES_IDS.length];
    private SurfaceView[] mSurfaceViews = new SurfaceView[SURFACE_RES_IDS.length];
    private SurfaceHolder[] mSurfaceHolders = new SurfaceHolder[SURFACE_RES_IDS.length];
    private boolean[] mSizeKnown = new boolean[SURFACE_RES_IDS.length];
    private boolean[] mVideoReady = new boolean[SURFACE_RES_IDS.length];
    int i = 0; // index of video playout

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
         setContentView(R.layout.multi_videos_layout);

        // create surface holders
        for (int i = 0; i < mSurfaceViews.length; i++) {
            mSurfaceViews[i] = (SurfaceView) findViewById(SURFACE_RES_IDS[i]);
            mSurfaceHolders[i] = mSurfaceViews[i].getHolder();
            mSurfaceHolders[i].addCallback(this);
            mSurfaceHolders[i].setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }
    }
```

Comment: try using TableLayout. with rows and columns OR nested linear layouts

Comment: @UmaAchanta Your answer was the simplest and worked. Best is nested linear layouts. I have 2x2 now; But do you happen to know how I can set the width of two horizontal ones to be half of screen?

Comment: nested layout will work only for fixed data

Comment: you can divide screen width by using weight concept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way which worked for me was using nested `linearLayout`, as below (2x2). The only problem I have right now is I don't know how to set the height of horizontal layouts be exactly half of screen height!

Anyone has any ideas for that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/video_1_surfaceview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/video_2_surfaceview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/video_3_surfaceview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/video_4_surfaceview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but this not not what you question for. this is not grid view you can get here only 4 surfaceView

Comment: Right; I have to manually change it everytime. I asked for an exact answer unfortunately none of the answers helped.

Comment: for both inner linear layouts you have to set hight=0 and weight=1 for each one. next you need to set weightsum=2 for parent or outer layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example out and see how it works for you.

```
<GridLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/grid_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

     <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/video_1_surfaceview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/video_2_surfaceview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/video_3_surfaceview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/video_4_surfaceview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/video_5_surfaceview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/video_6_surfaceview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: I don't know why my videos do not run in this layout. Want to try it yourself? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70475776/multiPlayer.zip

Answer (score 1):

The conception is create a linearLayout for row and create another linearLayout for column to add it.  Add this code in onCreate method

```
    int column = 3;
    int row = 4;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(Your  RelativeLayout_in_main_activity_id);
    LinearLayout rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    rowLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    relativeLayout.addView(rowLayout);
    for (int i = 0; i<row;i++) {
        LinearLayout columnLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        columnLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        for (int j = 0; j<column;j++) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            columnLayout.addView(textView ); 
        }
        rowLayout.addView(columnLayout);
    }
```

Hope this answer is what you want.

Comment: I'm very new to Android; can you apply it to my project here? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70475776/multiPlayer.zip

Comment: In onCreate method ,and  to your activty_layout you need to create a relativeLayout, You need to change your TextView layout_ parms.If you feel not easy to use try to use LayoutInflator instead.

Comment: I have no textView; I have multiple surfaceView! I was trying to insert it in onCreate() but I was confused.

Comment: It's ok ,just replace textView with surfaceView. What point do you confuse?

Comment: So you mean instead of creating surfaceViews in the Style.layouts.xml, I should create them in code?

Comment: There is a piece of code as initialization that gets the list of surface views. This is run before that code: `private static final int[] SURFACE_RES_IDS = { R.id.video_1_surfaceview, R.id.video_2_surfaceview};`

Comment: btw, that `Your  RelativeLayout_in_main_activity_id` is what? I don't have any relative layout!

Comment: It doesn't run. I updated the piece of code in my question for onCreate() method.

Answer (score 1):

```
<GridLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/grid_layout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:columnCount="3"
android:rowCount="2">

 <SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/video_1_surfaceview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="0" />

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/video_2_surfaceview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="0" />

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/video_3_surfaceview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_row="0" />

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/video_4_surfaceview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="1" />

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/video_5_surfaceview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="1" />

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/video_6_surfaceview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_row="1" />
```

Comment: Did you already look at the other answer? What is different for yours?!

Comment: positions for each surfaceview.

Answer (score 0):

GridLayout may not work because of its inner implementation ([a set of infinitely thin lines that separate the viewing area into cells](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html)). Try using a container designed to display views efficiently such as a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) or its new cousins, such as the [HorizontalGridView](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView) or the [VerticalGridView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/VerticalGridView.html), you can find a set of useful examples for the latter [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.support.v17.leanback.widget.VerticalGridView)

Comment: I'm very new to Android; can you apply it to my project here? dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70475776/multiPlayer.zip

Comment: Serious of what?! I was playing out with those examples, but ran into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Please check it like this. First define your grid view in your **MainActivity** or wherever you want. then make a **custom_layout**

**GridView** in **Activity class**

```
 <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:columnWidth="170dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />
```

create a layout now.
in that layout you can put your image view or **surface view** whatever you want like

```
  <SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/video_1_surfaceview"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    />
```

**Only one**  **is enough**

now create an **AdapterClass** and inflate your custom layout. that's it 
Let me know if you still having any problem.

Comment: I'm new to Android; these AdapterClass and whatnots are a bit problems. Did you look at my onCreate() above?

Comment: I just did it in the xml file. If I put two surfaceViews in a tableView, I get an error